# SPSS - Multiple Graphs

Tags: spss

I create a graph in SPSS and can go in and change the colours and other visual properties. But then when I create another graph, it uses the old default properties again.  I can see the code when I create the graph but not for the changes I make to its appearance. I have to create 150 graphs and want them all to come out with my preferred colours etc but can’t work out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing a single graph has no effect on default settings.  You have two ways to do what you want.

1. Edit the preference settings via `Edit>Options>Charts`.  You can set default colors, color cycles, line styles, patterns, etc but not everything
2. Make a chart.  Edit it to your satisfaction.  Then use `File>Save` Template to save the properties you want to have apply to other charts.  You get to pick from a long list of properties.  Then, for future charts, include this template in the creation code.  In the `Chart Builder`, you can set this template using the `Options` subdialog.

Answer (score 3):

Step A

When you are done editing a graph use file -> Save template

For next graph choose your saved template

Your settings will now be used in your new graph. In this way you can create a bunch of templates depending on what kind of graph and layout you would like.